# Google Cloud Messaging on web, cant get token

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-messaging

I need some help with firebase cloud messaging, because I really don't know, why I can't get token.

I tried download sample project, clear all not necessary stuff and implement it as on this video [Getting Started with Firebase Cloud Messaging on the Web - Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCBCudx58g)

My sample code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Firebase Cloud Messaging Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "MYAPPKEY",
      authDomain: "PROJECT_NAME.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://PROJECT_NAME.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "PROJECT_NAME.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.requestPermission()
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Have perm");

        return messaging.getToken();
      }).then(function(token) {
        //never get here
        console.log(token);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Err: ", err);
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But I never get the token and when I'm debugging it in console, messaging.getToken() is really returning Promise, but pending with no value:

```
messaging.getToken()
Promise__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

After 4 hours of trying I releazed, that "authDomain" have to be HTTPS server url

Comment: haha, but why i just can requested token but can't after that